# How to ensure graphics size change with change in window size?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, picturebox

I am drawing a rectangle in a picturebox. when the user manually changes the window size the rectangle size does not  change. how do i make it resize?. i am drawing in the Paint event Thanks a lot